# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, callback

Following is the code in which I am getting `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`.

```js
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here, though if I do -

```js
function print2(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

this is working fine.

[image]

Comment: @Andreas Did you click on "Run code snippet"?

Comment: The exact wording of error messages depends on the browser. I get the error he reports in Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since there's no semicolon after the function, the snippet gets interpreted as the following:

```
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

Which means that it's trying to index into the function. Add a semicolon either after the function, or before the array literal:

```
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
};

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

or

```
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}

;[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

More about Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion here: [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/996081)

Comment: Wooow..this is a clear case of `adding semicolons in your code` though its optional :)

Comment: Could be! I personally use [prettier](https://prettier.io/) which makes errors like these really stand out.

Answer (score 7):

You need a semicolon at the end of the variable declaration.

```js
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
};

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

Without the semicolon, it's being treated as

```js
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

`[1,2,3,4]` is being interpreted as an property accessor, not an array, and the comma operator returns the last value `4`. Since the function doesn't have a `4` property, that returns `undefined`, and then you try to call `.forEach()` on that.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing semicolon after `FunctionExpression`.

```
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
}

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

change to

```
const print2 = function(x, y) {
  console.log(x*y)
};

[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think, rather than `[1,2,3,4].forEach( x => print2(x, 20) )`, you should use a variable like `array.forEach(x => print2(x, 20));`

For example code given below:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4];
const print2 = function(x, y) {
    console.log(x*y);
};

array.forEach( x => print2(x, 20) );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record.
I'll like to add, that I've experienced the same error using that code

```js
var createFiltersList = function() {
        window.filterMenu.forEach(function(text) {     /* <== error here */
            filterList.push({
                text: text,
                expr: text !== ALL ? [DevAV.filterField, "=", text] : null,
                type: DevAV.filterCaption,
                custom: false
            });
        });

        var customItems = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
        Array.prototype.push.apply(filterList, customItems);
    };
```

My problem was that I haven't set any value for window.filterMenu so filterMenu was null so forEach is not applicable to null.
Once that a set a array of value to filterMenu, the error got away.