# Google Sheets Script Editor - JS range.length error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a custom function in Google Sheets which will copy a range of values vertically a given number of times:

[image: original]

So that when applying repeat(A1:A4,3), it pastes vertically A1 3 times, A2 3times, A3 3 times and A4 3 times.

[image: result]

My attempt seems to work well, displaying the result correctly, but it gives an error which I don't understand.

```
function repeat(range,number){
   var result = [];
   const l = range.length;
   for (var i=0;i<len<i++)
      for(var j=0;j<number;j++)
         result.push(range[i])
      return result;
}
```

The error displayed by Apps Script is:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", indicating line 3. Please feel free to guide me on how to use this and whether there are easier/better options, as I am a beginner in both Apps Script and JS.

Comment: Please show how you defined range and number in your function invocation.  Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Isn't that repeat(A1:A4,3) as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are using this as a custom function so your range is actually a 2 dimensional array of values not a Class Range.  Look up Custom Functions in the documentation.

If you insert this code into a spread:

```
function repeat101(values,count) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

Like this =repeat101(A1:A4,3)

Where A1:A4 looks like this:

| 1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Then look at your executions log you get this:

Executions Log: Jul 9, 2021, 2:08:58 PM Info    [[1],[2],[3],[4]]

If your familiar with with using the debugger you will immediately recognize  that as a 2 d column array

```
function REPEAT101(values, count) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let oA = [];
  values.forEach(r => { for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) { oA.push([r[0]]) } });
  return oA;
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned I am a beginner, so no, I am not familiar with using the debugger.

Comment: Would you be able to adapt the answer so that it adjusts the method I was trying? I am struggling to adapt the JS coded answer from here, which is closer to my knowledge, and it is working perfectly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266412/repeat-range-of-items-multiple-times-in-google-sheets

Comment: Sorry when I began working with Google Apps Script I already new quite a bit about Javascript.  Back then it was assumed that knowing Javascript was a prerequisite.

Comment: The function you presented says info null for me and asked for permission, but it still does not return anything. In the answer presented before, the author is using range for the same thing as I am trying to.

Comment: You say in your question your trying to create a custom function.  What do you mean by a custom function?

Comment: Here's what the Google Apps Script says about custom functions : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: My function is working in my spreadsheet just fine.

Comment: The first function in my code was just to be able to get a look at what a range input in a custom function looks like.  So I just ran it to view executions and see that it's a two dimensional array.

Comment: Can you update the function to match the one provided in the answer I presented please? It is not working for me for some reason (no idea why, I don't doubt your method), but this talk is not useful and I know what Google Apps Script says about custom functions., that is the page where I started the work on this from. The fact that I don't know JS should not be an impediment. If I knew, I wouldn't have asked here in the first place. I don't need a high school lesson of doing my homework. Please provide alternatives so I can actually learn something.

Comment: The function you added via edit works , but it still says TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

Comment: So, I suppose that is some sort of thing with the debugger or something that I wish you would help with, rather than arguing with me about my lack of knowledge. However, I do appreciate the addition, although you should have said in the comment you added it, rather than saying first function. It took me a while to find out, and it's just making things harder for a beginner.

Comment: You need to define values by selecting a range when you insert the function into a cell in the spreadsheet.  Here's what mine looks like: `=REPEAT(A1:A4,3)`

Comment: Are you using V8 runtime?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look further into it, I appreciate the support. Yes, V8 is enabled in the project settings automatically, and I am trying to switch it off, but it keeps getting back on saying something about a missing ; 
I believe I am not declaring the array properly, but I cannot tell why.

Comment: Exactly how are you typing the function into the cell?

Comment: =REPEAT(B3:B6,5)
The problem is not in the cell, because the values are pasted correctly. The issue is with the debugger, because it throws the undefined error for both my code and for your code, although both functions work correctly. However, I did not know this until running your code as well.

Comment: You probably have other functions with the same name.  Try changing the name.

Comment: I do not, I have changed the name for both my function and yours many times by now. I have found several sources mentioning that this is an issue with the semicolon, but I cannot get it to work, regardless of where I am adding or removing it.

Comment: It is doing the same thing for every call of an array for which I am using .command after

Comment: I don't know what to tell you I changed mine to `=REPEAT101(B3:B6,5) ` and it works just fine.  This is the whole point of a [mcve] because if we can't reproduce it then we are not likely to be much help in resolving the issue.

Comment: I mean array.length or array.forEach or array.typeof

Comment: There is no array.typeof that I know of

Comment: What about the other two? I have read something here about it, but no matter how I edit it, it's throwing the same error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070657/typeerror-cannot-read-property-foreach-of-undefined-javascript/62070791

Comment: Nevermind this, it is working regardless, thank you for the solution. Would you be able to help with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323183/transpose-n-rows-to-one-column-in-google-sheets-script-editor