# Transpose N rows to one column in Google Sheets - Script Editor

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I would like a custom function to transpose a large number of rows into one single column please.

Small example (the actual one has thousands of rows)

[image]

Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rowstocolumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let col = [];
  vs.forEach(r => {
    r.forEach(c => col.push([c]))
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,col.length,col[0].length).setValues(col);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that is very much appreciated. It worked perfectly. Can I also get a version of the function with parameters so I can apply it for a specific range selected? It would help me learn easily by applying

Comment: Actually I think it would simply provide you with an alternative to learning all you have to do is to parameterize this line `sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`  it's almost all right there in front of you except for one item.  There I gave you a hint.